# Setting up my development environment for a small development team

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I am setting up a new development environment for a small team, currently we are only 2 developers, and mainly we will be using the following frameworks:-

1. Asp.net MVC framework to build some web application from scratch.
2. SharePoint 2010 or 2013 to build an intranet/extranet application.

So I have settled on the following development tools to be able to build asp.net MVC web applications + to extend and build SharePoint application:-

1. Visual studio 2012 for building the web applications for both MVC & SharePoint.
2. Team foundation server 2012, to have version control, bug tracking , etc.

My question is the following:-

1. Since I will need the SharePoint 2013 templates so I cannot go with the express version of visual studio 2012?  since the VS express version does no provide enterprise features such as SharePoint templates.
2. But will using TFS express suit my situation?
3. I have read that Microsoft provides a free plan where I can get free Visual Studio Professional 2012 & Team Foundation Server with all the enterprise features since I have less than 5 users (in my case 2 developers) and of course I can upgrade the free plan when the team grow.
4. So will getting the free plan from Microsoft work well in my case, especially 
   for having the SharePoint templates inside the visual studio 2012?

Best Regards

Comment: Are you a startup? If so have a look at the BizSpark program. http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/Offers/Default.aspx

Comment: not a startup, but the company used to buy all of its products and applications from external suppliers. But now they have start building their own software development department to build their own internal applications.